# Error Code on Prompt

Tags: shell, arch-linux, zsh, prompt, error-handling

Currently I have `!` in the right prompt of [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) as follows:

```
export RPS1="%B%F{red}!%f%b"
```

As I use [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux), and command history is not being synced throughout its panes (unfortunately), the numbers are almost useless for me.

I tried to set `RPS1` to `?` and `$?` to display **return code** / **error level** of the command but with no success.

I remember I had to set:

```
setopt promptbang
```

for `!` to be interpolated (interpreted, expanded).

How to achieve such a prompt on the right side of the command-line indicating the previous command's result in error number.

[image]

An example screenshot of my current prompt having `>`, `>>`, and `!` as `$PS1`, `$PS2`, and `$RPS1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show the return status of the previous command you can use the *prompt escape* `%?`.

```
RPS1='%B%F{red}%?%f%b'
```

You can even switch the color depending on the exit status:

```
RPS1='%B%(?.%F{green}.%F{red})%?%f%b'
```

Or only display anything, if the command returned with an error:

```
RPS1='%(?..%?)'
```

This will color the output green if `%?` evaluates to `0` and red otherwise.

---

In order to substitute arbitrary parameters (like `$?`) you would need to enable the `PROMPT_SUBST` option:

```
setopt promptsubst
```

In that case you need to sufficiently quote the parameter to prevent it from being substituted at declaration time. For example by using single quotes or by quoting `$` with an `\` inside double quotes.

```
RPS1='$?'
RPS1="\$?'
```

BTW: It is not necessary to export `RPS1` (or any other shell configuration parameter) for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `${?##0}` into `PS1` wherever you want a nonzero exit code to be displayed.  If the exit code of the previous command is zero, it will be truncated to a null string (`0` with all leading zeros removed is a null string).

```
user@host:~
$ bash
user@host:~
$ exit 4
logout
user@host:~ 4
$
```

In relevant part from my `PS1`, I have `\e[31m${?##0}\n\[\e[$(((($?>0))*31))m\]`.  If the exit code from the previous command is nonzero, display it in red.